# What is the command to unstake / unlock loki from a service node on the loki network?

Tags: monero-forks, loki, proof-of-stake, loki-wallet-cli

What is the command line command to unlock / unstake my loki from a loki service node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
request_stake_unlock <service node key>
```

The guide can be found here: https://docs.loki.network/ServiceNodes/SNFullGuide/#step-8-unlock-stake